# Troubles installing Anaconda on Python

Tags: linux, software-installation, datascience-anaconda

I am currently attempting to install Anaconda on my Linux shell. I download and check the hash code of my downloaded file, provide a directory and so on. However, my Unix refuses to execute the script. Once I type

```
$ sudo bash Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

the prompt gives:

```
ERROR: did not recognize option '', please try -h
```

`-h` gives nothing relevant. I tried this with a x32 and Python 2.7 versions as well, to rule out incompatibility of version in the environment.

As far as I can find, I can not need any pre-installed software. On [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), I found that I needed the `buns` package, which I installed but nothing improved. The `buns` package is probably required for actual functioning of the program.

Is there anyone who can help me out? I am not sure what the error means or how it is constituted, as it provides me with no information.

Comment: What is your output of `which getopt` ?

Comment: try without sudo first.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille;

I have tried this without sudo, but similar results are obtained. I thought sudo-rights were the problem at first

@hg8 I get this;


PROMPT:
/usr/bin/getopt: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `{'
/usr/bin/getopt: line 19: `local({'

Comment: what is the first line of Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh ?

Comment: Hi @GerardH.Pille; the first line reads;

#!/bin/sh

I assume that the coding is correctly downloaded, because the hashes are identical, though. But maybe you can do something with this information.

Comment: Your /bin/sh does not understand the Anaconda script (which is probably bash).   What gives `ls -l /bin/sh` ?

Comment: I just read that "bash ./Anaconda3..." should ignore the shebang on the first line.   Can you try running the script itself?   So, just `./Anaconda3...`

Comment: Hi Gerard, the output for your first suggestion;


lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 sep  1  2016 /bin/sh -> /bin/bash

The second suggestion doesn't work. It gives the same error (option '')

The header file is present when I use the "dir" command

Comment: This is what I get: `$ ./Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh          

Welcome to Anaconda3 5.0.1

In order to continue the installation process, please review the license
agreement.
Please, press ENTER to continue
>>> 
`   So there is something special with your installation.

Comment: If you're interested, I can tell you how to debug that script.  You just need to insert a line `set -x` after the first one, save the file, calculate its size with `wc -c Anaconda3...`, edit the file again and replace the second 550796553 by the new size.  Run the script again to find where it bails out.